# How do I use the `group` in where clause for the comparison in following query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT name FROM oc_filter_group_description fgd
     WHERE f.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id AND
           fgd.language_id = '1' ) AS `group`
FROM oc_filter f
LEFT JOIN oc_filter_description fd
    ON (f.filter_id = fd.filter_id)
WHERE fd.language_id = '1' AND fd.name LIKE '%FAB%'
```

Comment: can you paste some input data and what is your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your query so that it does not use any correlated subqueries in the select clause, but rather only joins:

```
SELECT f.*, fgd.name, fd.*
FROM oc_filter f
LEFT JOIN oc_filter_group_description fgd
    ON f.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id AND
       fgd.language_id = '1'
LEFT JOIN oc_filter_description fd
    ON f.filter_id = fd.filter_id
WHERE
    fd.language_id = '1' AND
    fd.name LIKE '%FAB%' AND
    -- fgd.name = 'some name'
```

This approach makes the `name` column directly accessible in the `WHERE` clause.  If you want to keep your current approach, then MySQL offers an option via the `HAVING` clause, where aliased items in the select clause can be directly used:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT name FROM oc_filter_group_description fgd
     WHERE f.filter_group_id = fgd.filter_group_id AND
           fgd.language_id = '1' ) AS `group`
FROM oc_filter f
LEFT JOIN oc_filter_description fd
    ON (f.filter_id = fd.filter_id)
WHERE fd.language_id = '1' AND fd.name LIKE '%FAB%'
HAVING `group` = 'some name';
```

The `HAVING` clause in MySQL, when `GROUP BY` does not appear, sort of functions as an overloaded `WHERE` clause, and aliases are available for use.

Comment: , Thank you  very much  for offering to help out with this Query.

Comment: @JagrutiMetaliya Not a problem at all.  I answered on a cell phone by the way :-)